# Issue with second flexbox when stacking them

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm currently having an issue where my FlexBox is not positioning my nested element all the way to the right with the `justify-content: flex-end;` and `align-items: flex-start;` properties.

In the picture below, the big grey box is in `panel` class which houses the initial borders. Within the `panel` class is the `panel-price-box` which should create a secondary box and send it to the top right position of the initial box.

The code is in SCSS.

CSS:

```
.product
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border: $border-small $panel-color;
    border-radius: $border-radius-small;

    &-price
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-start;

        &-box
        {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-left: 1px solid grey;
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
            height: 25px;
            width: 100px;

        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-price-box"></div>
</div>
```

The picture below is the live example of what my end result is.

[image: End result is linked here]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: the html does not contain `product-price` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```css
.product
{
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border: $border-small $panel-color;
    border-radius: $border-radius-small;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;


    &-price
    {
        &-box
        {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-left: 1px solid grey;
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
            height: 25px;
            width: 100px;

        }
    }

}
```